# A way to search form table in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I looked for a way to scan database for a specific table. For example i have:

```
Database: system_ultimate Table: system_settings
```

And let us say, that one doesn't know precise name of the table. He only knows, that it is some how connected to the word ***settings***. **How could he search for that table name then?**

I understand, that usually people who develop know, what they develop, but I'm trying to get hang of MVC and I'm trying to stay as far away as possible from direct communication with table using the name.

I know, that to see all tables I could use `SHOW TABLES;`

Comment: ...so you want to find a table whose name you don't know?

Comment: Yes. Correct. Something like look for records with author name = 'some_text%'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%settings';
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Don't know yet which is optimal, but this is the shortest one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get these from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'system_ultimate'
 table_name LIKE '%word%'
```

more on this can be found on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score 0):

The `word settings` would have to match a certain set of criteria or `naming convention` so that you could calculate the correct names, just like any MVC framework would. If the table name differs, then the coder would specify tghe table name in the model.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has database **information_schema** in this DB Mysql holds all DB names tables names and columns names.

You can get all tables columns with select:

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA` , `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'myDb'
AND `TABLE_NAME` LIKE ('test%')
```